# Pain with using multiple monitors

Tags: mac, display

Today I got a new 13 inch mac book pro. I have a 30 inch asus monitor which I use as a secondary display. The resolution of the monitor is higher than the macbook pro.

when I move the mouse from my secondary display (the asus monitor) to my macbook, it gets stuck. I think the mouse can only move when you are in the resolution area of the macbook.

So I have to move the mouse in the center of the screen and only then I can move it to the macbook.

This is very annoying. Is there a way I can move the mouse between two monitors without really centering it first?

Answer (score 1):

To rearrange the position of the displays, please see [Configuring Mac OS X for Multiple Displays](https://documentation.apple.com/en/aperture/usermanual/index.html#chapter=B%26section=4%26tasks=true).

Comment: I did it... but still the mouse gets stuck on the areas where there is no corresponding position on the other monitor. I wonder why can't the mouse move to the other screen and remain at the top? why should it block

Comment: Because there's nothing there for it to move to. I guess it _could_ warp to the side of the other display, but I prefer it this way myself.